# Technology for app like teamviewer on android

Tags: android, sockets, streaming

I am troubling what technologies was used/should be used on an app like teamviewer. I am thinking about an application for android which can auto record any action on the screen of android device, then provide a streaming-line to a PC application to view that screen on real time.

Anyone can give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it.

This is how you do it for android. few steps are required, but you can do it...

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42491/how-to-remote-view-and-control-your-android-phone/

Hope this helps.
Thanks.